# "The connection is already Open (state = Open)"

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I'm new to C# development and while trying to create a simple application, I ran into an issue. I am trying to populate a ComboBox based on the SelectedIndexChanged property of the first ComboBox. Visual Studio states at the second cn.Open (in private void cboCities_SelectedIndexChanged), that the connection is already open. However, from my code I believe I have closed it already? What is it I am doing wrong? Any and all help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = \Program Files\ParkSurvey\ParkSurvey.sdf; Persist Security Info = False; Password = *");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand command = cn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Cities ORDER BY Name ASC";
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        cboCities.ValueMember = "CityId";
        cboCities.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboCities.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cboCities.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }

    private void cboCities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboCities.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            cn.Open();
            string Cities = cboCities.SelectedValue.ToString();
            SqlCeCommand command = cn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Parks WHERE CityId ='" + Cities + "'";
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            cn.Close();
            cboParks.ValueMember = "ParkId";
            cboParks.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cboParks.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cboParks.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should change your code to declare a new connection in each method and wrap it in a using statement.  Then it will close and dispose automatically.

Comment: If you remove the open command from the `SelectedIndexChanged` it won't shoot anything ? or does the database connection seem like it's open?

Comment: You are trying to duplicate the effort of the ConnectionPool. So follow @cadrell0's advice: keep the connections local to each method.

Comment: I will repost as an answer so that you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code to declare a new connection in each method and wrap it in a using statement. Then it will close and dispose automatically.